# analog of java wildcard (generic type) in c #

Tags: java, c#

I rewrite the code with java on .net c # confronted with the problem of transfer classes with wildcard. There are two classes

```
public abstract class Client <T extends Connection <? >>
public class Connection <T extends Client <? >>
```

I thought we could have done so

```
public abstract class Client <T> where Connection <U>
```

but it turned out that even here does not work

```
public abstract class Client <T, U> where Connection <T, U>
public abstract class Connection <T, U> where Client <T, U>
```

so how to get out of the situation?

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

```
public class Connection<T>
{
}

public abstract class Client<T, U> where T : Connection<U>
{
}
```

Comment: I need to contact the descendants of the two classes . So it does not work .